# Cannot navigate specific screen FCM onDidReceiveNotificationResponse cause of MyApp() home

Tags: flutter, navigation

When I click on the notification in flutter, I navigate to a specific page, but due to the class that I gave to the home parameter in the MyApp widget, it does not redirect to the page I want.

When I give this to material page home ;

```
home: ResponsiveSizer(
    builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
      return const HomeScreen();
    },
  ),
```

it is working it navigate , but when I chage the return class with LoginScreen;

```
home: ResponsiveSizer(
builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
  return const LoginScreen();
},
```

),

Navigation process does not working ;

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            const SpecificScreen(whereCome: "notification")));
```

Does not it navigate because it's in the same tree widget tree LoginScreen() and Specific Screen() ?

**How to I solve this issue ?**

Answer (score 0):

if your app is closed then the onDidReceiveNotificationResponse function will not call only the app will open otherwise if the app is already open then this method will work

I solved the issue by doing the bellow :

create an indicator to check if a notification is opened or not, you can use a database to check what the last notification posted and check if it is opened or not

Comment: OnDidReceiveNotificationResponse does not work when I give the home parameter, which is the first class of the application, LoginScreen or HomeScreen, but it works when I enter a different class. I think my problem is in the routing processes.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the navigation isn't working because the LoginScreen is the initial screen of your app and is set as the home parameter in the MaterialApp. When you navigate to SpecificScreen, you are trying to push a new route onto the navigator stack, however, it is not working because the navigator is already on the LoginScreen route.

To solve this issue, you must change the home parameter to a blank Scaffold in your MaterialApp and then use a Navigator widget to navigate between screens. Here's an example:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: LoginScreen(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Go to Specific Screen"),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) =>
                    SpecificScreen(whereCome: "notification"),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SpecificScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String whereCome;

  const SpecificScreen({Key? key, required this.whereCome}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Where I come from: $whereCome"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```